# How to convert AudioBufferList containing AAC data to CMSampleBuffer

Tags: swift, avassetwriter, cmsamplebuffer, video-toolbox, audiobufferlist

I'm using `AudioConverter` to convert uncompressed `CMSampleBuffer` being captured via `AVCaptureSession` to `AudioBufferList`:

```
let status: OSStatus = AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(
            converter,
            inputDataProc,
            Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque(),
            &ioOutputDataPacketSize,
            outOutputData.unsafeMutablePointer,
            nil
        )
```

My output asbd is set up as follows:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription
- mSampleRate : 44100.0
- mFormatID : 1633772320
- mFormatFlags : 2
- mBytesPerPacket : 0
- mFramesPerPacket : 1024
- mBytesPerFrame : 0
- mChannelsPerFrame : 1
- mBitsPerChannel : 0
- mReserved : 0
```

I'd like to convert `AudioBufferList` back to a `CMSampleBuffer` containing compressed data so that I can then write it to an mp4 file using `AVAssetWriter` (I have already figured out how to do it with video), but so far with little. I've tried consulting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514701/how-to-convert-audiobufferlist-to-cmsamplebuffer) but in that case there's PCM data and it doesn't seem to be usable here.

I have access to `AudioBufferList` as well as the presentationTimeStamp of the original sample. I've tried the following but I'm not quite sure how to calculate numSamples and whether this approach makes any sense or not:

```
 func createCMSampleBuffer(_ data: UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer, presentationTimeStamp: CMTime) -> CMSampleBuffer? {
    let numSamples = // not sure how to get this

    var status: OSStatus = noErr
    var sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?
    var timing: CMSampleTimingInfo = CMSampleTimingInfo(
        duration: CMTime(value: CMTimeValue(numSamples), timescale: presentationTimeStamp.timescale),
        presentationTimeStamp: presentationTimeStamp,
        decodeTimeStamp: CMTime.invalid
    )

    status = CMSampleBufferCreate(
        allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
        dataBuffer: nil,
        dataReady: false,
        makeDataReadyCallback: nil,
        refcon: nil,
        formatDescription: formatDescription,
        sampleCount: CMItemCount(numSamples),
        sampleTimingEntryCount: 1,
        sampleTimingArray: &timing,
        sampleSizeEntryCount: 0,
        sampleSizeArray: nil,
        sampleBufferOut: &sampleBuffer
    )

    guard status == noErr else {
        return nil
    }

    status = CMSampleBufferSetDataBufferFromAudioBufferList(
        sampleBuffer!,
        blockBufferAllocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
        blockBufferMemoryAllocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
        flags: 0,
        bufferList: data.unsafePointer
    )

    guard status == noErr else {
        return nil
    }

    return sampleBuffer
}
```

In the end I did manage to create a `CMSampleBuffer`, but when I try finishing writing, I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x174442ac0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12735 "(null)"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12735), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can share some research work on this may it will help you ...

`CMSampleBufferSetDataBufferFromAudioBufferList returned error: -12731`

solution :- https://lists.apple.com/archives/coreaudio-api/2014/Mar/msg00008.html

or also [Converting AudioBuffer to CMSampleBuffer with accurate CMTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857219/converting-audiobuffer-to-cmsamplebuffer-with-accurate-cmtime?noredirect=1&lq=1)

may it will help you ...:)

Comment: it's better reference material

Answer (score 1):

So, I've managed to get some progress done (but still far from making everything work). Instead of constructing CMSampleBuffer as above, I instead managed to make the following (somewhat) work:

```
CMAudioSampleBufferCreateWithPacketDescriptions(
        allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
        dataBuffer: nil,
        dataReady: false,
        makeDataReadyCallback: nil,
        refcon: nil,
        formatDescription: formatDescription!,
        sampleCount: Int(data.unsafePointer.pointee.mNumberBuffers),
        presentationTimeStamp: presentationTimeStamp,
        packetDescriptions: &packetDescriptions,
        sampleBufferOut: &sampleBuffer)
```

The key here is to obtain the packetDescriptions from the compression process:

```
let packetDescriptionsPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>.allocate(capacity: 1)

AudioConverterFillComplexBuffer(
                converter,
                inputDataProc,
                Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque(),
                &ioOutputDataPacketSize,
                outOutputData.unsafeMutablePointer,
                packetDescriptionsPtr
            )
```

The audio CMSampleBuffer seems to be correctly created now but when I append it, audio doesn't play and it creates weird timing glitches with video.